# How access the replies, retweets and likes of a particular tweet using tweepy?

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, tweepy, tweets, twitter-streaming-api

I am running the code below. The problem is to find **1. All replies 2. Number of Retweets 3. Number of likes** of a particular tweet id. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29928638/getting-tweet-replies-to-a-particular-tweet-from-a-particular-user) but unable to understand. Being a newbie, kindly tell me in simple.
Any help will be appreciable.

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
import json

consumer_key = '*********************'
consumer_secret = '*********************'
access_token = '*********************'
access_secret = '*********************'

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

tweet = api.get_status("756856874763423744")
print(tweet)
```

Answer (score 0):

use tweet._json['retweet_count'] which will make you will get retweet count.