# Twitter API - Retrieve all replies to a certain tweet

Tags: python, twitter, twython, reply

I am trying to use Twitter API with the Python wrapper Twython and I want to retrieve all replies (the comments below a tweet) to a certain tweet find using some patterns.

At the moment to achieve this, I perform the search of a string, I retrieve the `screen_name` field of `user` field in the response, related to the original tweets and then I use again the API in order to search the latest tweets directed to the user, using in the query the substring `to:screen_name`.

Is there a better solution? The only questions related to this topic that I found were written in '14 and I hope that, in the mean time, there were some improvements.

Comment: I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29928638/getting-tweet-replies-to-a-particular-tweet-from-a-particular-user) that talks about retreiving tweet replies from a particular tweet from a specific user. And this [Github code](https://gist.github.com/edsu/54e6f7d63df3866a87a15aed17b51eaf) that explains, and I quote, `Twitter's API doesn't allow you to get replies to a particular tweet`, but he seems to have a work-around.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try even this way. But I hoped the were be something that is not a work around in order to call APIs as least as possible.

Comment: Maybe Twitter wants to avoid too much scrapping and voluntarily asks for specifics in order to get results. ;)