# Ideas for scraping reply for each tweet

Tags: python, twitter

Hi I'm new to scraping data from twitter and I've been working on a project to collect tweets and their replies. I scraped the tweets using twitter API , but I couldn't scrape their replies. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Use their API instead of scrapping the website.

Answer (score 0):

***Scraping*** is not using API. API is a comfortable method to get data while scraping is doing it manually. If you want to get replies, but the API doesn't provide them, you can use selenium. It is well-known library used for scraping data.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter API does not have an end-point to get replies to a tweet for free users, but there are some ways to achieve what you want, although there may be some limits on how many tweets you can get.

Check-out tweepy library, I think you could use the [search method](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html#search-methods) as is explained in [**this question(How to get the replies for a given tweet with tweepy and python?
)**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52307443/how-to-get-the-replies-for-a-given-tweet-with-tweepy-and-python). To better understand how to use the tweet object, you should definitely [check the docs out](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/object-model/tweet).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by:
You want to get replies of @barackobama and Tweet Id is 1234 just example.
Search tweets having @barackobama is tweet text. then make filter on InrplytweetId=1234
by this method you can get replies of this tweet.